# How to get value of a TextView which is in another activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to get the value of a TextView which is defined in another activity? I am using android studio.

Comment: You might not be able to do that. Instead, try to get the text and pass it to another by the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use intents for passing values to another activities.
in first activity:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("YOURKEY", yourTextViewValue);

   startActivity(intent);
```

Access that intent on next activity

```
   String textViewValue= getIntent().getStringExtra("YOURKEY");
```

Answer (score 0):

First activity (which has TextView)

```
SecondActivity.launchActivity(this, textView.getText().toString())
```

Second Activity (which need the text value)

```
public static void launchActivity(Context context, String textViewValue) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("textValueKey", textViewValue)
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if (getIntent() != null) {
      String textViewValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("textValueKey");
  }
  ...
}
```